# Return only first match with Inner Join

Tags: sql, magento, ssms

I have this query below and it works. However, it takes over 30 mins to run. Essentially, the sku field is unique, but the tables it is joining with have multiple values that correspond to the entity_id. I only want to return the first value it finds.  I understand that the way I am doing it now works, but it is not efficient at all.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for the weird code sample. Couldn't get it to format under the code option.

Thanks!

```css
SELECT
FROM
(
 SELECT DISTINCT substring(sku, 1, 
 (
 SELECT CASE
  WHEN charindex('-', sku)-1 = -1
  THEN 0
  ELSE charindex('-', sku)-1
 END
 )) AS sku, 
 CAST(cpet.value AS varchar(max)) AS 'DESCRIPTION', cpev.value AS 'URL_KEY', CONCAT('https://azureedge.net/catalog/product', cpemg.value) AS 'image', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY sku) AS RowNumber
 FROM imp_mg.CATALOG_Product_Entity cpe
 INNER JOIN 
 imp_mg.CATALOG_Product_Entity_Text cpet
 ON cpe.entity_id = cpet.entity_id
 INNER JOIN 
 imp_mg.CATALOG_Product_Entity_Varchar cpev
 ON cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
 INNER JOIN 
 imp_mg.CATALOG_Product_Entity_Media_Gallery cpemg
 ON cpe.entity_id = cpemg.entity_id
) AS a
WHERE a.RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT top 1 substring(sku, 1, 
        (
        SELECT CASE
            WHEN charindex('-', sku)-1 = -1
            THEN 0
            ELSE charindex('-', sku)-1
        END
        )) AS sku, 
        CAST(cpet.value AS varchar(max)) AS 'DESCRIPTION', cpev.value AS 'URL_KEY', CONCAT('https://azureedge.net/catalog/product', cpemg.value) AS 'image', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY sku) AS RowNumber
        FROM imp_mg.CATALOG_Product_Entity cpe
        INNER JOIN 
        imp_mg.CATALOG_Product_Entity_Text cpet
        ON cpe.entity_id = cpet.entity_id
        INNER JOIN 
        imp_mg.CATALOG_Product_Entity_Varchar cpev
        ON cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
        INNER JOIN 
        imp_mg.CATALOG_Product_Entity_Media_Gallery cpemg
        ON cpe.entity_id = cpemg.entity_id

ORDER BY sku
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ran the query and killed it at 27 mins.  I am going to try and handle all the joins in the Azure pipeline instead. Hopefully that will lighten the load of the actual queries.